# how can I determine if a library (lets say "cursesw") is standardly distributed with a unix/linux release

Tags: linux, unix, shared-libraries, ncurses, curses

Im writing an application that should use cursesw/ncursesw
in a variety of different Unix/Linux platforms.

How can I know if a distribution installed from scratch
contains these libs (or any other libs) by default.
(without the need to install a fresh instalation and check :))

It looks like a simple question, 
but Im looking arround the web for some time now.
not finding a clue.

Can some one give a lead?

Thanks in advance...

OK!!!
There is great advancement with the help of "Visa is Racism" user in [I need to list the programs which have a specified shared library linked to them in UNIX/Linux (like ldd but vice versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543419/i-need-to-list-the-programs-which-have-a-specified-shared-library-linked-to-them) question.
I used: ldd /bin/* |grep -B 20 ncursesw and got exactly what I wanted. A list of the native programs using ncursesw. this pretty much gives me an indication that ncursesw is distributed as a native library in ububtu for instance.

That way I found out that /bin/nano and /bin/rnano use ncursesw in ubuntu 12. **But now I remain with the question**: is nano a native program distributed with ubuntu 12.

**Is there a way to know that? (Which are the programs distributed with a linux distribution by default)**

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear enough. I need to know in advance that linking to the lib in compilation/linking time will not create any kind of problem in installation and runtime. Isnt the info I need known beforehand in any doc or release note of the different distributions?

Comment: curses and ncurses are default libraries in the main known Unix Linux distributions. I know that curses is released with Unix platforms and ncurses is released with linux platforms. I know which platforms I want to use. I want to know if their standard release contains curses/ncurses/w

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for the presence of libraries at install time and act on the answer.  Look up the GNU tool [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) to get more details.  (You might not want to actually use autoconf, but it is the conventional way of dealing with these things when you are targeting a variety of Posix platforms)

If you target specific package managers (apt-get, rpm) you can list your pre-requisites and the package manager will take responsibility for making sure the pre-requisites are present.

Or you can static-link everything.

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear enough. I need to know in advance that linking to the lib in compilation/linking time will not create any kind of problem in installation and runtime. Isnt the info I need known beforehand in any doc or release note of the different distributions?

Comment: Such information will always be incomplete, since anyone can create a distribution tomorrow that will be different from any distribution made before.  If you target specific package managers (apt-get, rpm) you can put your pre-requisites there, and the package manager will take responsibility for making sure the package is present.  Or you can static-link everything.

Comment: curses and ncurses are default libraries in the main known Unix Linux distributions. I know that curses is released with Unix platforms and ncurses is released with linux platforms. I know which platforms I want to use. I want to know if their standard release contains curses/ncurses/w