# I need to list the programs which have a specified shared library linked to them in UNIX/Linux (like ldd but vice versa)

Tags: linux, unix, shared-libraries, ldd

ldd command in unix/linux lists all the dinamically linked libraries of a program.

how can I determine the reverse question:
what is the list of programs linked to a specified shared library?

I need a way of getting a list of programs that use "libz" for instance.

is there a command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt there would be. That would require keeping a database of all executables and remembering what they depend on, which may be possible if you only install software from a specific channel, but it certainly won't be able to track executables you produce otherwise. Not to mention such a database is largely useless and therefore not attractive.

If you need to find such executables however (e.g. to know if it's safe to remove the shared library), you can easily find **most** of them. The key is that most of the executables you have are inside `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or similar locations. So all you need is to run `ldd` on all files inside those directories and `grep` for the library you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks man! This really helps. I used:                              ldd /bin/* |grep -B 20 ncursesw                                     and got exactly what I wanted. A list of the native programs using ncursesw. this pretty much gives me an indication that ncursesw is distributed as a native library in ububtu for instance.

Comment: I found out that /bin/nano and /bin/rnano use ncursesw in ubuntu 12. But now I remain with the question: is nano a native program distributed with ubuntu 12. Is there a way to know that? (Which are the programs distributed with a linux distribution by default)

Comment: @YairKarmy, "Native" wouldn't be my choice of word, since often native shows a deeper bind. Nevertheless, if you want to know what software ships with a certain Linux distribution, well just install one and look at the software before installing others! In Ubuntu you could use the software center to look at the installed packages. In other distributions you can use their respective package managers.

Comment: Thanks but I need to write an application that uses cursesw/ncursesw on a large variety of OSs and machines. Initially I was trying to determine which platform has by default which one of curses/ncurses/cursesw/ncursesw/xcurses/xcursesw lib.I thought that if I find a program that uses one of these libs and this program is installed with the OS release by default then I know that this lib is installed with release by default also. Get each machine and install from scratch seems a lot of work.

Comment: There should be some kind of documentation which programs are brought with the release. or maybe I should see which programs where installed on the same date and time of the OS release?

Comment: @YairKarmy, there probably is such a documentation, but I never needed one, so I don't know. However, what you want to do has a completely different solution. With `apt` and many other Linux package managers you can specify a dependency to a package, so whoever installs your package those dependencies would get installed too. With OSX I don't really know, but I suspect there is a similar solution. Windows is stupid, so everyone ships their software with all the dlls they need (and therefore you have many many duplicate dlls).